# PHP floatval bizarre parsing

Tags: javascript, php, doctrine-orm, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I have some calculations on the client side with JavaScript.

> var total = (((3 * 24) / 100) + 3); //result is 3.7199999999999998

I need to store this `3.7199999999999998` number in the database as it is.
Database is on MySQL, i use Doctrine 2 for ORM, and entity has the precision set to `/** @Column(type="decimal", precision=32, scale=16, nullable=false) * */`, but after saving i see that in database is just the number `3.72`, wtf ? After some checking i found that doctrine uses `floatval` and after executing this `floatval(3.7199999999999998)` you get `3.72`!! why?

Is there a workaround for this ? like telling doctrine not to use the floatval and store the value as it is? also i dont want to use varchar for this column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not expert of doctrine2. but can't you change datatype tp `double`.?

Comment: no, i can not. the result is the same `3.72`

Answer (score 2):

3.72 is the correct value. The 3.7199999999999998 result is due to floating-point imprecision in JavaScript (See: [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)). I'd suggest using [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) in your JavaScript code to avoid this.

```
var total = (((3 * 24) / 100) + 3).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: So because JavaScript is broken i should avoid 16 digits precision and to use only a precision of 2 digits ? And what to do if i need a higher precision ?

Comment: If you need higher precision, use the [BigDecimal library for JavaScript](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js) or [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js)

Answer (score 1):

3.72 is actually the correct value. It would appear that JavaScript has a precision error when performing this calculation.

Comment: Then how to get back `3.7199999999999998`  number from `3.72` in JavaScript ? Because with this round up i get more errors using `3.72`.

Comment: @Constantin Not sure why you want the incorrect value

Comment: I need back this wrong number because i need to calculate back the percent later, and to be always the same.

Comment: @Constantin - perhaps that should be included as part of the question. It sounds like there is more going on and there may be another solution.